# Asynchronous Rest Service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, asynchronous

I have created a Rest based web service Using jersey. I want to make it Asynchronous web service using polling mechanism.  I want to know the service side implementation.

Requirements on the web service side:

1. Create request tokens and send it to client
2. Manage the tokens
3. Send response when client requests for the response using this token
4. Run the the service business logic in different thread

I am not finding useful posts and code snippets. Everywhere the mechanism is discussed but how can we implement this?